# Load application.properties when the config server is not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins

My project has a bootstrap.yaml and a config server that deliver its appropriate profile. Everything is working great but I have to accomplish some others task like CI and CD.

My problem comes because the Jenkins machine is not allowed to resolved external domains and try to compile and run the Spring boot app without an a profile.

So my question is:

1. **Is there a way to load application.properties when the config server
   is not resolved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a natural way based on the order in which Spring Boot loads `PropertySource`s.

You can include properties you want to be applied in `application.properties`.

In case config server is not available - properties from `application.properties` will be used. If config server is available - you'll receive properties from there.

You might also want to disable config server connectivity for your CI using environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED=false`.